# How to round a time to the nearest 15 minute segment

Tags: mysql, time, rounding

How can I round times in MySQL to the nearest 15 minutes (e.g. 0,15,30,45)?

Comment: Can you show us anything you have done so far? :-)  Then we could suggest accordingly.

Comment: Why not use a `timestampdiff` with `mod`? Btw I take my earlier comment as I ddnt notice the answer is by you. You could have just updated your question by appending your code :-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR((TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME())+450)/900)*900)
```

In this example I have used CURTIME() for the input time, but you can use any time field.

900 seconds=15 minutes (the period to round to), 450 seconds is half that (to provide the rounding element).  I've tested with 1800/900 to get nearest half hour, should work with others (600/300 for 10 minutes etc).

Comment: Remove `450` if you need corresponding 15-min block

Answer (score 21):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) / 900,0)*900);
```

This can be generalized to round to any time value.  900 seconds = 15 minutes.  You can replace the 900 with any other rounding factor.

Comment: Yes the 900 can be changed to any amount of time but the code you provided alone will always round down.

Comment: use CEIL() instead of TRUNCATE()

Comment: For even better (faster) results use [integer division](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) (which rounds down, not up but that shouldn't matter) - or subtract the `MOD 900` from the number instead of divide and multiply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some rough code that I used that got the results really close to what I wanted. Because I didn't use seconds I just chose minutes near the half way point.

```
SELECT
       CASE 
            WHEN minute(timeIn) BETWEEN 0 and 7 THEN SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(timeIn) DIV 3600) * 3600)
            WHEN minute(timeIn) BETWEEN 8 and 22 THEN ADDTIME(SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(timeIn) DIV 3600) * 3600), '00:15:00')
            WHEN minute(timeIn) BETWEEN 23 and 37 THEN ADDTIME(SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(timeIn) DIV 3600) * 3600), '00:30:00')
            WHEN minute(timeIn) BETWEEN 38 and 52 THEN ADDTIME(SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(timeIn) DIV 3600) * 3600), '00:45:00')
            WHEN minute(timeIn) BETWEEN 53 and 59 THEN ADDTIME(SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(timeIn) DIV 3600) * 3600), '01:00:00')
       END as 15_min
    FROM
      clock.punches;
```