# How do I collapse the same rows between a date/time range?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I want to collapse rows with the same URL parameter. This is my current query:

```
SELECT ADDTIME(date,time) as fecha, bytes, url FROM traffic;
```

And this is the result:

```
2014-07-07 09:05:56         14K     http://feeds.feedburner.com 
2014-07-07 09:05:56         14K     http://feeds.feedburner.com 
2014-07-07 09:11:56         14K     http://feeds.feedburner.com 
2014-07-07 09:17:37         350K    http://www.cmmail.com   
2014-07-07 09:17:40         5K      http://www.cmmail.com   
2014-07-07 09:17:40         10K     http://www.cmmail.com   
2014-07-07 09:20:26         1K      http://www.google.com   
2014-07-07 09:20:48         1K      http://www.google.com   
2014-07-07 09:20:49         1K      http://www.cronista.com 
2014-07-07 09:20:49         1K      http://www.cronista.com
```

What I want is to group the same URL between each 5 minute interval, and sum `bytes`. In other words, I want this result:

```
2014-07-07 09:05:00         28K     http://feeds.feedburner.com 
2014-07-07 09:10:00         14K     http://feeds.feedburner.com 
2014-07-07 09:15:00         365K    http://www.cmmail.com   
2014-07-07 09:20:00         2K      http://www.google.com   
2014-07-07 09:20:00         2K      http://www.cronista.com
```

Comment: Don't store date and time as separate entities!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the date_time type to a unix epoch (number of seconds) with [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestampand),
divide by 300 (= 5 min) with the [integer division operator **`DIV`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) thereby removing fractional digits, which effectively round down to 5 minute intervals. Should be *simplest* and *fastest*.
Then aggregate.

You can convert back with [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) after multiplying by 300 again to have a nice display.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDTIME(date,time)) DIV 300) * 300) AS fecha5
     , url
     , sum(bytes) AS sum_bytes
FROM   traffic
GROUP  BY 1,2;
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d41d8/809)

Answer (score 3):

In other words, you need to round your `fecha` datetime down to the nearest 5-minute mark, and then `GROUP BY` the modified `fecha` column and the `url` column.

There are some questions already that address rounding time values; you could use the top-upvoted answer from  [How to round a time to the nearest 15 minute segment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13708294/2359271) to group your result set like this:

```
SELECT 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(
        TRUNCATE(
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
                ADDTIME(date, time)
            ) / 300, 0
        ) * 300
    ) as fecha_5_min,
    SUM(bytes) as bytes_total,
    url
FROM
    traffic
GROUP BY fecha_5_min, url;
```

If the indentation does not make the technique clearer to you, here are the exact steps for creating `fecha_5_min` from `fecha`:

- Convert your original `fecha` to some number of seconds, using [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp);
- Divide that number of seconds by 300 seconds (i.e., 5 minutes);
- `TRUNCATE()` the result to 0 decimal places, to remove any remainder;
- Multiply that number of "three-hundreds-of-seconds" by 300 to get back to unit seconds;
- Convert the seconds back to a date and time, using [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

---

Be sure to read @Erwin's answer as well for a good point about using `DIV` instead of `/` to avoid the `TRUNCATE()` call.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! .. with this 2 answers a made it work. The parenthesis on the group by gave me an error: "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" , so I used Erwin's method, and tah dah!