# convert hours to hh:mm in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have data which is below has email and working hours (in hours formate), expecting output of working_hours to hh:mm:ss

```
select d.email,TRUNCATE(sum(e.hours),2) as "working_hours"
from users d inner join proj_time e on d.id=e.user_id
WHERE start_time BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND
group by d.id,d.email
```

| email | working_hours |
| --- | --- |
| vij@sic.com | 5.77 |
| skiol@sic.com | 4.24 |
| olps@sic.com | 2.69 |
| dvia@sic.com | 6.12 |

i tried below query to change working_hours, BUT getting leading zeros, requested output to remove leading zeros (00:) from working_hours output

```
select d.email,SEC_TO_TIME(TRUNCATE(sum(e.hours * 60),2)) as "working_hours"
from users d inner join proj_time e on d.id=e.user_id
WHERE start_time BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND
group by d.id,d.email
```

| email | working_hours |
| --- | --- |
| vij@sic.com | 00:05:46.20 |
| skiol@sic.com | 00:04:14.40 |
| olps@sic.com | 00:02:41.40 |
| dvia@sic.com | 00:06:07.20 |

**Expected output would be like**

| email | working_hours |
| --- | --- |
| vij@sic.com | 05:46 |
| skiol@sic.com | 04:14 |
| olps@sic.com | 02:41 |
| dvia@sic.com | 06:07 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Change Datetime Format in an MySQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545799/how-to-change-datetime-format-in-an-mysql-table)

Comment: i required only time to be change like decimal hours to hh:mm format

Answer (score 2):

+all
thanks for the help.
I got answer to my question,

`SEC_TO_TIME(ROUND(TRUNCATE(sum(e.hours * 3600),2)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test (email VARCHAR(255), working_hours DECIMAL(10,2));
INSERT INTO test VALUES
('vij@sic.com',     5.77),
('skiol@sic.com',   4.24),
('olps@sic.com',    2.69),
('dvia@sic.com',    6.13);
SELECT email,
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(working_hours * 3600)) total_time,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(working_hours * 3600)), ':', 2) truncated,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(working_hours * 3600 + 30)), ':', 2) rounded,
       DATE_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(working_hours * 3600)), '%h:%i') formatted_truncated
FROM test
GROUP BY 1;
```

| email | total_time | truncated | rounded | formatted_truncated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vij@sic.com | 05:46:12.00 | 05:46 | 05:46 | 05:46 |
| skiol@sic.com | 04:14:24.00 | 04:14 | 04:14 | 04:14 |
| olps@sic.com | 02:41:24.00 | 02:41 | 02:41 | 02:41 |
| dvia@sic.com | 06:07:48.00 | 06:07 | 06:08 | 06:07 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ybKrVvod)