# How to round off a time difference to nearest 0.5 hours in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Mysql noob here. I'm trying to round off the difference between 2 dates calculated using timediff to the nearest 0.5 hours. time_to_sec(timediff(midnight,start ))/3600

I saw an example using floor ie floor(val *2+0.5)/2 which I implemented:

floor(((time_to_sec(timediff(midnight,start ))/3600)*2)+0.5 but as soon as I included the 0.5 I get an error code 1064.

Any ideas on how to get the solution?

Comment: 5 left brackets 4 right..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a time to the nearest 15 minute segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708294/how-to-round-a-time-to-the-nearest-15-minute-segment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
SELECT ROUND((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(midnight, start)) / 3600) * 2) / 2 AS rounded_hours FROM your_table;
```

Comment: A question about this answer, please: If I run it as a SELECT it returns some results containing 0.5, but if I run it as an UPDATE/SET:                                                      

UPDATE my_table SET start_until_midnight = ROUND((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(midnight, start)) / 3600) * 2) / 2; it rounds to whole numbers. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Don't worry about this I figured it out. It was how I was declaring the column name...