# print 15, 30, 45, 60 minutes of every hour

Tags: php

I want to draw time in 15 min interval. I want my program prints 15, 30, 45, 00 minutes of current time. Suppose time is 1:00 pm I want it to be printed for 15 minutes. After 15 minutes it should print 1:15pm.

Here is my codes its working good but shows time after 30 seconds.

Please check.

```html
<?php
//$getdate=date('Y-m-d');
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata" );

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone($timezone );
$time= $date->format( 'H:i:s A ' );
$getdate= $date->format( 'Y-m-d' );
$newarrdate=explode('-',$getdate);

$getdatefromarr=$newarrdate[0]."-".$newarrdate[1]."-".$newarrdate[2];
$gettime=explode(':',$time);
$hour=$gettime[0];
$amorpm=substr($gettime[2],3,2);

if($amorpm=="AM")
{
    $chamorpm="A.M";
}
else
{
    $chamorpm="P.M";
}

$currentitme=$hour.":".$gettime[1]." ".$chamorpm;

$minutearr=array(00,15,30,45);
$getarr1=array(01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14);
$getarr2=array(16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29);
$getarr3=array(31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44);
$getarr4=array(46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59);
$minutearr1=array(00=>00,01=>01,02=>02,03=>03,04=>04,05=>05,06=>06,07=>07,08=>8,09=>9,10=>10,11=>11,12=>12,13=>13,14=>14);
$minutearr2=array(15=>00,16=>01,17=>02,18=>03,19=>04,20=>05,21=>06,22=>07,23=>8,24=>9,25=>10,26=>11,27=>12,28=>13,29=>14);
$minutearr3=array(30=>00,31=>01,32=>02,33=>03,34=>04,35=>05,36=>06,37=>07,38=>8,39=>9,40=>10,41=>11,42=>12,43=>13,44=>14);
$minutearr4=array(45=>00,46=>01,47=>02,48=>03,49=>04,50=>05,51=>06,52=>07,53=>8,54=>9,55=>10,56=>11,57=>12,58=>13,59=>14);
$valtime=$gettime[1];

$changearr=array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$makerarry=array(00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09);

if(in_array($gettime[1],$minutearr))
{
    $querytitme=$hour.":".$gettime[1]." ".$chamorpm;
}
else if(in_array($gettime[1],$getarr1))
{
    if(in_array($valtime,$makerarry))
    {
        $getmaketime=substr($valtime,1);
    }
    else
    {
        $getmaketime=$valtime;
    }

    $caltime=$gettime[1]-$minutearr1[$getmaketime];

    if(in_array($caltime,$changearr))
    {
        $newtime="0".$caltime;
    }

    $querytitme=$hour.":".$newtime." ".$chamorpm;

    if($hour>=13)
    {
        $drawtimehour=$hour-12;
        $gethourfromdraw=$drawtimehour.":".$newtime." ".$chamorpm;
    }
    else
    {
        $drawtimehour=$hour;
        $gethourfromdraw=$drawtimehour.":".$newtime." ".$chamorpm;
    }
}
else if(in_array($gettime[1],$getarr2))
{
    $caltime=$gettime[1]-$minutearr2[$valtime];
    $querytitme=$hour.":".$caltime." ".$chamorpm;

    if($hour>=13)
    {
        $drawtimehour=$hour-12;
        $gethourfromdraw=$drawtimehour.":".$caltime." ".$chamorpm;
    }
    else
    {
        $drawtimehour=$hour;
        $gethourfromdraw=$drawtimehour.":".$caltime." ".$chamorpm;
    }
}
else if(in_array($gettime[1],$getarr3))
{
    $caltime=$gettime[1]-$minutearr3[$valtime];
    $querytitme=$hour.":".$caltime." ".$chamorpm;
    if($hour>=13)
    {
        $drawtimehour=$hour-12;
        $gethourfromdraw=$drawtimehour.":".$caltime." ".$chamorpm;
    }
    else
    {
        $drawtimehour=$hour;
        $gethourfromdraw=$drawtimehour.":".$caltime." ".$chamorpm;
    }
}
else if(in_array($gettime[1],$getarr4))
{
    $caltime=$gettime[1]-$minutearr4[$valtime];
    $querytitme=$hour.":".$caltime." ".$chamorpm;
    if($hour>=13)
    {
        $drawtimehour=$hour-12;
         $gethourfromdraw=$drawtimehour.":".$caltime." ".$chamorpm;
    }
    else
    {
        $drawtimehour=$hour;
        $gethourfromdraw=$drawtimehour.":".$caltime." ".$chamorpm;
    }
}

if($hour>=13 && $hour<20)
{
    $drawhour=$hour-12;
    if($gettime[1]>=0 && $gettime[1]<=14)
    {
        $drwatime=$drawhour.":"."15"." ".$chamorpm;
    }
    else if($gettime[1]>=16 && $gettime[1]<=29)
    {
        $drwatime=$drawhour.":"."30"." ".$chamorpm;
    }
    else if($gettime[1]>=31 && $gettime[1]<=44)
    {
        $drwatime=$drawhour.":"."45"." ".$chamorpm;
    }
    else if($gettime[1]>=44 && $gettime[1]<=59)
    {
        $getnexthour=$drawhour+1;
        $drwatime=$getnexthour.":"."00"." ".$chamorpm;
    }
}
else if($hour>=22 )
{
    $drwatime="Closed";
}
else
{
    $drawhour=$hour;
    if($gettime[1]>=0 && $gettime[1]<=15)
    {
        $drwatime=$drawhour.":"."15"." ".$chamorpm;
    }
    else if($gettime[1]>=16 && $gettime[1]<=30)
    {
        $drwatime=$drawhour.":"."30"." ".$chamorpm;
    }
    else if($gettime[1]>=31 && $gettime[1]<=45)
    {
        $drwatime=$drawhour.":"."45"." ".$chamorpm;
    }
    else if($gettime[1]>=46 && $gettime[1]<=60)
    {
        $getnexthour=$drawhour+1;

        if($getnexthour==12)
        {
            $disamorpm="P.M";
        }
        else
        {
            $disamorpm=$chamorpm;
        }

        $drwatime=$getnexthour.":"."00"." ".$disamorpm;
    }
}
```

This program also print about next time. Example it's 1:00pm it also prints 1:15. But I need help with to print current time for 15 minutes.

Comment: sorry for bad english.

Comment: I'm more worried about the code ;) Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2480679/3492835) for a way more compact solution to your problem.

Comment: Great code! And look at this post :) https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/674665684652064769?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw

Comment: this is showing next quarter time. but i want to show current time for next 15 minutes