# round minute to closest 15 minute

Tags: php

im trying to add 15 minutes to the current time and list it. but i need show it like below

```
15:30 
15:45 
16:00
16:15....
```

i used the below code

```
for($i = 15; $i <= 90; $i+=15)
        {   
            echo date("H:i",strtotime('+'.$i.' minutes'))."<br>";

        }
```

but i get the time like this

```
 15:24 
 15:39 
 15:54 
 16:09 
 16:24
 16:39
```

how can i round the minutes to be like 15,30, 45...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480637/round-minute-down-to-nearest-quarter-hour

Comment: I think the best way is to round the first date and after add 15 minutes. And not to round each time the date that you have calculate. Just for the performance and rapidity of your code.