# How to get carbon current time with X minute leap?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

E.G. If I want current date with 15 minute leap:
If now is :

```
2017-2-2 18:22
```

15 minute leap time will be :

```
2017-2-2 18:30
```

If now is :

```
2017-2-2 18:30
```

15 minute leap time will be :

```
2017-2-2 18:30
```

If now is :

```
2017-2-2 18:31
```

15 minute leap time will be :

```
2017-2-2 18:45
```

15:01 to 30:00 gives 30:00, 30:01 to 45:00 gives 45:00 etc...

Comment: I can write 50 lines algorithm but I am looking for some elegant solution...

Comment: Then show us what you have tried, we aren't gonna write your "elegant solution" for you.

Comment: @Epodax on no problem dude. I think question is legit and can really help someone in future. I will write my code...

Comment: Could you perhaps draw inspiration from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480637/round-minute-down-to-nearest-quarter-hour

Comment: @James yes this really help thanks...

Comment: I write a solution...

Answer (score -1):

Solution is :

```
public function minutesToQuarterHour($timestring) {
    $minutes = date('i', strtotime($timestring));
    return ($minutes - ($minutes % 15) + 15);
}

$time = '2016-10-04 15:59:00'; ///or any date get with carbon->now()
$minutes = minutesToQuarterHour($time);
$dateBase = Carbon::parse($time);
$dateBase = Carbon::parse($dateBase->format("Y-m-d H" . ':00:00'))->addMinutes($minutes);
echo $dateBase->format("Y-m-d H:i");
```

Comment: I don't get it why you make it so complicated? `$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); $now->addMinutes(15);` also do the trick

Comment: first I detect minutes addition, then I produce now time but hourly based, e.g. 2017 2-2 15:00:00 than I add minutes on this time...