# How to round up my given time is to thest last 15 minutes?

Tags: php

I am working with OT management system. I am calculating some OT value related to the each employee.now i want round up this OT value in last 15 min. How do i do it? Example values are given below.

```
07:17:46 need to be 07:15:00
06:25:25 need to be 06:15:00
```

Similar question: [Round minute down to nearest quarter hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480637/round-minute-down-to-nearest-quarter-hour)

Comment: `round up` -> `07:17:46` would actually be 8:15 - I believe you want to round down

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate as seconds are involved?

Comment: @michmackusa Yes you are right.

Comment: No need to reopen on a slight extension on the seconds.  Not every snowflake needs to be saved -- especially when no effort is shown.  https://3v4l.org/Bqi4t this is just one random answer from the other page that works just fine.  I have voted to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split into hours, minutes and seconds. Round the minutes down, fill with zeros and return.

```
function timeLastQuarter($timestr) {
  $time = explode(":",$timestr);
  return str_pad($time[0],2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).":".str_pad(((floor($time[1] / 15))*15),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).":00";
}
```

Example:

```
echo timeLastQuarter("15:55:00"); // 15:45:00
```

Comment: it working separately but in case it print nothing .i try to print as  '$table .='<td border border-dark>' . timePreviousQuarter($holifinalOT01) . '</td>';'

Comment: but it is not print nothing without timeLastQuarter its work .what is problem

Comment: $holifinalOT01 which hold the ot value

Comment: Seems like to have to learn PHP basics. Of course you have to print / echo the output and furthermore make sure that the input is a correct time string. If it is not working you have to debug whats wrong, the function itself is correct.

Comment: no no finnaly table will be print.

Comment: $table .='<td border border-dark>' . $holifinalOT01 . '</td> is printed correct value

Comment: Cool. Then you may accept the answer in order to close the question 

Comment: but round up function value is not print bro

Comment: Changed from echo to ŕeturn, just a little thing to notice. Copy the new function.

Comment: thank you bro .much appreciate beginner for legend help

Answer (score 1):

Create your own function to round/floor the value. You can explode the time, then subtract the reminder to make it rounded. **Example:**

```
function _floor($time) {
    $elm = explode(':', $time);
    $elm[1] -= $elm[1] % 15;
    $elm[2] = '00';
    return implode(':', $elm);
}

echo _floor('07:17:46') . PHP_EOL;
echo _floor('06:25:25') . PHP_EOL;
```

Demo at https://3v4l.org/LBKDp

Comment: This version rounds the seconds instead of the minutes. My edit fixed that but was rejected ...

Comment: not working bro .it will print 07:17:46 as it"s not 07:15:00

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check it now.